# count.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: linux, shell

I am ask to write a shell script to count number of lines 
in all ".cpp" in current directory.

However,when running my shell script, 
it said `count.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token "done"`
I do not know what is wrong.

can anyone tell me how can solve this problem ?
Thanks for your help.

```
#!/bin/bash

summary=0
for i in $(find . -name *.cpp -print) 
do
count=$(wc -l $i)
let summary+=count
if [$count -eq 1]
then 
    echo "$i : $count line"
elif [$count -gt 1]
    echo "$i : $count lines"        
done

if [$summary -eq 1]
then 
echo "TOTAL: $summary   line"

elif [$summary -gt 1]
echo "TOTAL: $summary   lines"
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a `fi` before the `done`. You must end the `if` statement with a `fi`, then you have the `done` to end the `for` loop.

Example: **UPDATE** The following example is not all that is needed to make this script correct. I leave it here as is, because that was the reason for the "initial" error the OP saw. Read on for more fixes.

```
for i in $(find . -name *.cpp -print) 
do
  count=$(wc -l $i)
  let summary+=count
  if [$count -eq 1]
  then 
      echo "$i : $count line"
  elif [$count -gt 1]
      echo "$i : $count lines"        
  fi
done
```

Also, maybe it is just a copy/paste error, but at the end of your code/script you're entirely missing the `fi`.

There are a couple of errors in your script. First of all, here is the correct version:

```
for i in $(find . -name *.cpp -print)
do
     count=$(wc -l $i | cut -f1 -d' ')
     let summary+=$count
     if [ $count -eq 1 ];
     then
       echo "$i : $count line"
     elif [ $count -gt 1 ];
     then
       echo "$i : $count lines"
     fi
done
```

Fixes:

- The output of `wc -l` is like `12 ./filename`, so to use just the line count, you have to extract that. I used `cut` for that purpose.
- The `let` command requires that you actually add a literal value or a variable. So you need to use `$count` and not just `count`, which is just the string count and can't be added to something else.
- You need to put `;` after the test conditions.
- You need to introduce an `elif` block with a `then`, just like the `if` block itself.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have added "fi" in the loop and at the end of the code. but it is still showing "syntax error near unexpected token 'fi' "

Answer (score 0):

```
if [$count -eq 1]
then 
    echo "$i : $count line"
elif [$count -gt 1]
    echo "$i : $count lines"
done
```

should be

```
if [$count -eq 1]
then 
    echo "$i : $count line"
elif [$count -gt 1]
    echo "$i : $count lines"
fi                           # << this line is new
done
```